# Tagging post cable installations

Tags: networking, cable, cable-management

So I got a main station and 5 substations in our warehouse. I've got hired after all cable jobs are done. Now, my biggest challenge is to tag all cables, because they ran cables without marking them. So, please share some information and best practices to tag post cable installation. I think I have to test all of them, but maybe you guys would have some easier solutions.

Comment: `So I got a main station and 5 substations in our warehouse.` - What does that mean? - `I've got hired after all cable jobs are done. Now, my biggest challenge is to tag all cables, because they ran cables without marking them.` - What kind of cables? Presumably network cables. Why don't you try adding some detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI/TIA/EIA 606, Administrative Standard For Telecommunications Infrastructure, provides best practices, guidelines, and suggestions for how to create your label standard.

---

This depends on your jurisdiction, but, for instance, NFPA 70 (the National Electric Code for the U.S.) provides that all abandoned cable must be removed, and abandoned cable is cable that is not terminated and labeled on both ends, ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

Patch panels are usually labeled A-Z, 1-96 pending density, you'll want a tester with multiple remotes, something like http://a.co/iiNBjcx[image]